# MySQL - Load Data In File Returning Errors For Date Fields

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to load data from a .CSV file into a MySQL database using the following command.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "FILEPATH/EQUIPMENT.CSV" 
INTO TABLE EQUIPMENT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\R\N'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

However the following error is returned by MySQL when attempting to load information into the database:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'END_OF_LIFE' at row 1
```

This error doesn't make any sense. There as the value '0000-00-00' is not specified in row one for the data set. See example data set below.

```
+---------------+-------------+
| EQUIPMENT_ID  | END_OF_LIFE |
+---------------+-------------+
| B1010-V003    | 1800-01-01  |
| B1010-V001    | 1800-01-01  |
| B1010-V005    | 1800-01-01  |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Any one know why the system may be returning this error? (I have tried changing the dates to more reasonable values but this does not work either).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/usr/bin/mysql --local-infile=1 -u$DB_user -p$DB_pw --database=$DB_database < $working_dir/load_ic2_loc_batch.sh 2>> $logfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Am I meant to run this command via command prompt? Can you elaborate on its use a bit more?

Comment: sorry i sent the wrong file, the above one is meant to run in a batch file and start the following:#!/bin/sh 

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<path>/<filename>.CSV' 
INTO TABLE <table-name> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 0 LINES;

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out what was wrong. It was due to the line endings being incorrectly specified as capitals in my script (I guess the MS DOS line endings in the input CSV file are case sensitive). See corrected script below.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "FILEPATH/EQUIPMENT.CSV" 
INTO TABLE EQUIPMENT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```